# How to sample small set of images for training a model from a large images folder in r?

Tags: r, machine-learning, split, sample-data

I have a very large folder of images (train_dir), as well as a CSV file containing the class labels for each of those images(train_df). Because the data is huge, I'd like to take only a sample of images (say 25%) along with labels(train_df); How would I be doing this in R Programming?

My "train_dir" folder has around 150,000 images = ('1.png','2.png',....)
 and my CSV file looks something similar to
[CSV file - train_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsvKG.png)

What would be the approach to go about making r-script that can do this?

Comment: Maybe `n<- nrow(train_df);i<- sample(n,n*0.25)` and then use the index `i` to subset `train_df` and select the corresponding image files.

Comment: I can work around sampling my CSV file but I find it really challenging to split a folder of images. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: By to split a folder do you mean to move the files to another folder? Or to read just those files?

Comment: Just read the files I sampled

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of the following code will

1. get an subset of the row numbers, to serve as an index into `train_df`;
2. Subset `train_df`, and get a sample of PNG *filenames*. Since column `"id"` is a factor, convert it to character.
3. To each filename, apply a read PNG function. In this case I have used `png::readPNG`, but others can be used in the same way.

The code then becomes the following.

```
perc  <- 0.25
n <- nrow(train_df)
i <- sample(n, n*perc)
png_filenames <- as.character(train_df[i, "id"])

png_files <- lapply(png_filenames, function(x){
  png::readPNG(x, native = TRUE)
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your time but that's not exactly what I need. I just need to sample 1000 images to work with from the total 150,000 images in my 'train_dir' folder.

Comment: @Horseman1901 That's even simpler, instead of `perc<-0.25` do `m <- 1000` and use it where the code has `n*perc`.